# NSIS - Install path problems

Tags: nsis

I'm having some path problems in the default installation. My code below:

http://pastebin.com/7vrCuLiZ

And my problem is that the default path to install is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Advanlab\DISK1\Common\Borland Shared\BDE\" instead of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Advanlab"

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vfoxytj1sbvqs5a/helpnsis.png

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT:
It only happens if the folder Advanlab already exist :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""` command is probably picking up this directory, try  `InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString"`

Comment: But should I comment the line before and add that? or should both exists?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the default installation directory in your NSIS script?

```
; The default installation directory
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\xxx
```

Comment: Can't you see the pastebin link? I tried post here the code but was a little messy :s

Comment: Yes, line 48 in the pastebin: InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\Advanlab"

Comment: Could not see any problem... If you try changing the "SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\DISK1" to another folder, what happens?